# 80s SF Novel, Space Cloud vs Interstellar Feudal Kingdom

Tags: story-identification

80's SF novel, not by a big name.

Set in a feudal interstellar empire of perhaps a hundred worlds. From the point of view of an aristocratic fleet captain who falls in love with his commoner mistress and starts to question the social system. Simultaneously a space cloud/amoeba appears at the fringes of the empire and goes from a rumour to a nuisance to a mortal threat as it begins moving inward, enveloping planets and consuming all life on them.

Our hero falls foul of the emperor and eventually volunteers to lead a suicide fleet to draw the creature out of the kingdom. <del>I have the vague memory of "Fingalan Conspiracy" as the title, but haven't found anything remotely resembling that title.</del>

Added- There is a pretty good chance it was a yellow cover gollancz series circa 1984, but I haven't seen anything similar on the gollancz lists I have seen online (anyone know of a definitive gollancz yellow cover list? - it was pretty much a guarantee of quality).

Comment: You space amoeba sounds a bit like the "Thread" in the dragonriders of Pern. But I did't actually read the books, they are probably very different in the other respects.

Answer (score 7):

You may be thinking of [*The Fingalnan Conspiracy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11590) by [John Rankine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rankine) (pseudonym of [Douglas R. Mason](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1724)). If so, one of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?11590) may ring a bell. Unfortunately, I know nothing about this book, I'm just going by the title.

Comment: Useful. Turns out this is not the book. But it has sparked the memory that I read this pair of books on the same holiday. Amusing that I remember the story of one, and the title of the other. PS good work tracking down the title - I did try!

Comment: If you can figure out which edition of *The Fingalnan Conspiracy* you read (for instance they all have different covers) that you get you pretty close to knowing what year the book you're looking for came out.